# How to take physical backup of MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, backup, windows

I am trying to find out some tool which can take physical backup of `MYSQL` database. Like `mysqlbackup` but it is not open source. There is `mysqldump` but i want to take physical backup. Can someone please suggest me some tool to take backup of MYSQL db on `windows`. And i am using `Innodb` as my database engine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You literally do not need a third party tool.

## STEP 01

Find out the path to the data by running

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';
```

For this example, let's suppose it is `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL 5.6\data`

## STEP 02

Pick a destination folder to copy the data directory

For this example, let's pick `D:\MySQLBackup`

## STEP 03

Create batch file called `C:\RunMySQLBackup.bat` with the the following commands

```
@echo off
set MYSQL_USER=root
set MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
set MYSQL_CONN=-u%MYSQL_USER% -p%MYSQL_PASS%
set MYSQL_DATA=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL 5.6\data
set MYSQL_BACK=D:\MySQLBackup
mysql %MYSQL_CONN% -ANe"FLUSH TABLES; SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown=0;"
net stop mysql
xcopy /s %MYSQL_DATA%\*.* %MYSQL_BACK%\.
net start mysql
```

## CONCLUSION

Just run `C:\RunMySQLBackup.bat` on demand or add it to the Windows Scheduler. This is just a rough backup script and it only keeps one copy.

This is not the first time I discussed this. I have another post [MySQL backing up MyISAM tables by copying the physical files - and automating the process](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77820/mysql-backing-up-myisam-tables-by-copying-the-physical-files-and-automating-th/78106#78106) for copying an all-MyISAM database.

You should think about doing mysqldumps since you can get the data at a point-in-time. Should you want to go back to mysqldumps, I have another post I wrote on how to do mysqldumps in Windows with named backup filenames based on the data and time ([mysqldump with automatically generated export name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60964/mysqldump-with-automatically-generated-export-name/60968#60968)).

Comment: The InnoDB shutdown mode. If the value is 0, InnoDB does a slow shutdown, a full purge and a change buffer merge before shutting down. If the value is 1 (the default), InnoDB skips these operations at shutdown, a process known as a fast shutdown. If the value is 2, InnoDB flushes its logs and shuts down cold, as if MySQL had crashed; no committed transactions are lost, but the crash recovery operation makes the next startup take longer.